# Orbital dynamics or Celestial Mechanics symbol sets for Space SE

Tags: feature-request

Are there any schematic symbol sets for celestial mechanics or orbital dynamics terms like periastron, perihilion, apogee, perigee, etc.for incorporation into ?MathJax for Space SE?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It's mostly Latin and Greek letters, and these we do have in MathJax.